# Matlab: howto convert cell array of structs into struct array using colon operator?

Tags: matlab

Assume there is a cell array initialized with the following struct values.

```
% Phone book
phone_record{1} = struct('name', 'Bob', 'phone', '1233323');
phone_record{2} = struct('name', 'Mike', 'phone', '3245524');

% How to make such or similar one-liner work?
% phonebook(:) = phone_record{:}

% Expected:
% phonebook(1).name = 'Bob';
% phonebook(1).phone= '1233323';
% phonebook(2).name = 'Mike';
% phonebook(2).phone = '3245524';
```

Is it indeed possible to accomplish this w/o using *cell2struct* or for-loop indexing?
Can one use *deal* or similar?

Note: if you don't know the solution please spare the "best-practice" hinting or similar "hand-waving".

Comment: Please notice that array to array non-for-loop assigment works nicely as in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372619/understanding-colon-notation-in-matlab

Comment: It's probably poor form to tell people trying to help you to "please spare the "best-practice" hinting or similar "hand-waving"."  Condescension is rarely considered an incentive for people to take time out of their day to try to help you.

Comment: I apologize if that seems to be rude, but it is a technical question and the answer I got is very much to the point! Unfortunately, there are members in the community that like to make unnecessary comments ;-) or remarks like "wow, i would not do that if i were you..", "consider using use oop" and similar non-related nonsense. I have a technical question. My point is if you don't know the answer please think of restricting yourself saying just something and spare the time of other users that would read this knowledge base in search of a solution.

Comment: Hint: Matlab2014 offers a new promising datatype called **table** http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/table.html Somewhat into the direction of R's dataframes and python pandas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `cell2mat` :

```
cell2mat(phone_record)
```

> ans =
>
> 1x2 struct array with fields:
>
> > name
> >        phone

Comment: Thanks -- you just saved me a serious amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

```
phone_book = cat( 2, phone_record{ :})
```

does indeed use the colon operator, and will give the same result as cell2mat(phone_record).

Another non-colon solution is

```
cellfun(@(x) x, phone_record).'
```

with the benefit of transforming the structs on the fly, for example adding (missing) fields. Here we use the idendity, of course.